# WooCommerce dynamic menus

Tags: menus, plugins

I have a basic WordPress site set up with the Suffusion theme and the WooCommerce plugin. This is working well for the most part, however when I have folks click / hover over the "Shop" menu icon I would like this to dynamically drop down with the product categories I have defined.

How do I make this happen? I'm sure there is documentation on this subject but I'm not sure what to look for. I'm primarily a systems administrator.

Comment: It doesn't populate drop downs automatically. The parent menu needs to get clicked fr the product sub categories to display, and if the parent menu is linked to #, nothing gets displayed. How do I force sub menus to get displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suffusion supports WordPress nav menus. You'll find these in Admin > Appearance > Menus.

Simply add your product categories to the menu as children of the 'Shop' page. Assign the newly created menu to the "Navigation Bar Below Header" location.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen

Answer (score 14):

I might also add that sometimes the product categories is hidden. To see this act as follows:

Admin > Appearance > Menus. At the top right of the screen press "screen options" and activate product categories

Comment: That was a really useful bit right there. Appreciated.

Comment: This is the right-on-the-spot answer. I would accept it.